# How to run Either values by using CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

Java version : 11

I have a List, which contains many sublist and for each sublist I want to perform certain transformation/operations.

I want to perform this operation in non-blocking asynchronous fashion, so I am using CompletableFuture.

This is my operation:

```
public static List<String> convertBusinessObjectJson(List<BusinessObject> businessObjList) {
   
    List<Either> eitherValueOrException = {//omitted logic to convert to json}
    return eitherValueOrException;
}
```

> It returns a List of `Either` Objects, where Either holds, either runtime exception thrown by conversion logic or `String` result when conversion is successful.

This is my caller code:

```
mainList.forEach(sublist -> {
    CompletableFuture<List<Either>> listCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> FutureImpl.convertBusinessObjectJson(sublist));
});
```

Once the `CompletableFuture<List<Either>> listCompletableFuture` is received, I want to chain the operation,
As in

1. take `CompletableFuture<List<Either>> listCompletableFuture`, take exceptions only from list and, perform certain operation
2. take `CompletableFuture<List<Either>> listCompletableFuture`, take results only from list and, perform certain operation

Something like this (pseudo code):

```
mainList.forEach(sublist -> {
    CompletableFuture<List<Either>> listCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> FutureImpl.convertDSRowToJson(subDSRowList));
listCompletableFuture.thenApply(//function which pushes exception to say kafka)
listCompletableFuture.thenApply(//function which pushes result to say database)
});
```

Can it be done?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: You could use `whenComplete()` to provide a function that gets both the result and exception, checks for non-null parameters and handles the result accordingly. Or use the `allOf()` method to wait for all futures to be completed, then split the list into succeeded and failed futures and do bulk operations.

Comment: I have the List<Either> where Either has data or exception. ```whenComplete()```seems to accept BiConsumer, in my case it will be ```List<Either>``` and ```Throwable```, but the problem is I dont have exception thrown from ```convertDSRowToJson()``` method, so there is no throwable actually, only ```List<Either>```.

Comment: Well, in that case you'd need to get the `List<Either>` and check each element individually.

Answer (score 1):

You could try smth like this:

```java
var futureList = mainList.stream()
        .map(sublist -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> FutureImpl.convertBusinessObjectJson(sublist)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above would collect a list of `CompletableFutures`. Now what needs to happen is we need to wait for the completion of all those futures. We do this by:

```java
var joinedFutureList = futureList.stream()
        .map(objectCompletableFuture -> {
            try {
                return objectCompletableFuture.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
});
```

After that the separation would look smth like this:

```java
var exceptionList = joinedFutureList.stream()
        .filter(obj -> obj instanceof Exception)
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
var successList = joinedFutureList.stream()
        .filter(obj -> obj instanceof String)
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```